# Sending Content Builder templates/emails via the SOAP API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, content-builder

We are wanting to switch our organisation to Content Builder rather than stick with classic tools, and at the same time base the emails we send off a template editable via the UI, rather than a HTML string hardcoded in our script.

At present we create an email, create a data extension and send - all via the SOAP API.

I have been experimenting with the REST API and I can fetch assets without issue. What I can't figure out is if it's possible to:

1. fetch a template from the REST API and populate it to become an email
2. fetch a template from the REST API, populate it, and send it via the SOAP API

My only thought is to fetch it via the REST API, manually [compile and render](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/compiling-asset-model.htm) the template to a HTML string, and then send as at present.

Is this possible, and is there a better approach before "early 2017", when Content Builder will be added to the SOAP API?