# Fuel-Rest API using Content Builder send to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, fuel-sdk, content-builder

Is this even possible yet?  I have gotten my script up to the point of creating HTML emails in Content Builder and as I understand it, I have three options from there:

1. Send it to a Journey step.  My client does not have JB provisioned, so I cannot do that.
2. Send a single transactional email to a single user.  This isn't our use case.  We are trying to have automated mass sends.
3. Rebuild the email in SOAP and send it via classic content.  The client already has this in place and we really wanted to keep it in one email service (classic content vs content builder).  The whole project was to convert the old classic content/SOAP API send that was in place and swap to content builder/REST.

Is that it?  Is the functionality to send to a data extension just non-existent through REST and content builder?  I saw a few other threads that mentioned compiling it and sending the compiled version, but that is still creating it in classic content right?

EDIT: It looks like PeterB was trying to do this same thing two years ago.  Still not possible?

[Sending Content Builder templates/emails via the SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148588/sending-content-builder-templates-emails-via-the-soap-api?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the solution here is to use REST to create the email in Content Builder then send the Content Builder Template Based Email to SOAP by retrieving the Customer Key of the email.  Use that Customer Key to create a Send Definition in SOAP then send the way that you normally would.